# Converting app from paid to in-app purchase? How do I find out which users paid?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, app-store, in-app-purchase

I think I remember reading somewhere that there's a way to detect whether a user has paid for your app or not.

I'm considering changing from paid to in-app purchase, and wanted to know how I could check whether a user has previously paid, and thus should receive all in-app purchases for free.

Comment: I don't think its possible, if you don't have registration, or statistics in your old app. But its possible to check if the user has your old app installed in his device using [UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:yourAppURL]

Comment: You should ask this sort of questions at Apple's developer forums, not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go through the keychain to securely log your user's 'paying customer' status, but it does require first updating your app to implement keychain access and store user information before making the leap.

See our blog article about merging our paid and free app into one free, IAP enabled app [here](http://blog.digidna.net/post/74246563623/how-to-release-a-whole-new-app-and-keep-all-things).
We detail the process of making sure paying customers retain all privileges when moving to the IAP enabled new app.

Comment: There are far too many possible issues with this approach.

Comment: Some users aren't going to download and install the update that stores their "paying customer" status before they get the update that changes it to an in-app purchase.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the version of your app and determine if it's the old one (paid) or the new one. But you have to do this before switching to in-app purchase.

Or if you have anything set in the user defaults(and you can guarantee that anyone with older versions has it set up) , you can check if that objectForKey is present (returns anything else from nil) and consider that that user has made an update. And consider a new install else.

Comment: None of this works in many cases.